# When I run SAP HANA XSJS Application, it returns Error 404 - Found

Tags: eclipse, hana, xsjs

I'm new to the HANA environment. I'm trying to run "Hello world application", however every time I make changes it returns

> 404 - Not found
>
> We could not find the resource you're trying to access.
> It might be misspelled or currently unavailable.`

Note: I'm running it locally, I have not deployed it on the cloud yet.

[image]

SAP XS Engine is running

[image]

This is IDE I'm using and XSJS Application.
[image]

my .xsaccess:
[image]

my .xsapp:

[image]

I tried changing user privileges. In addition I also changed xsaccess couple of times to check CORS, networks, cache, etc.